# Deciphering a symbolicated crash log from Apple Review

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval, symbolicatecrash

I have an App that is repeatedly being rejected from Apple App Review for this reason:

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

*We were still unable to review your app as it still crashed on launch when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 13.5.1 on Wi-Fi. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.*

I am not able to reproduce what they are experiencing. I have tested on multiple iPhones and iPads on the same iOS version with no crashes.

This is the crash log they have sent. ( I have tried to symbolicate it myself in Xcode 11.5 )

Any ideas on what the log is indicating? I  cannot figure out anything pertinent from it.

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             XxxxxxxxxxxX [7724]

Identifier:          com.XxxxxxxxxxxX.XxxxxxxxxxxX
Version:             4 (2.7)
AppStoreTools:       11E608a
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.XxxxxxxxxxxX.XxxxxxxxxxxX [2534]


Date/Time:           2020-07-13 12:41:09.8242 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-07-13 12:41:09.6876 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.5.1 (17F80)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.06.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x19ad24300 __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19aa38c1c objc_exception_throw + 59
2   CoreFoundation                  0x19ac13e68 +[NSException raise:format:] + 111
3   UIKitCore                       0x19e7b1440 -[UISearchDisplayController initWithCoder:] + 87
4   UIFoundation                    0x19e388bcc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 727
5   UIFoundation                    0x19e388dec UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1271
6   UIFoundation                    0x19e323fe0 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
7   UIKitCore                       0x19e7fa11c -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1043
8   UIKitCore                       0x19eae6dbc -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2367
9   UIFoundation                    0x19e388bcc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 727
10  UIFoundation                    0x19e388dec UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1271
11  UIFoundation                    0x19e323fe0 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
12  UIKitCore                       0x19eae60ac -[NSCoder+ 7241900 (UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsAndTrackChildViewControllerIndexWithParent:forKey:] + 319
13  UIKitCore                       0x19e7fa2d4 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1483
14  UIKitCore                       0x19e738abc -[UITabBarController initWithCoder:] + 83
15  UIKitCore                       0x19eae6dbc -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2367
16  UIFoundation                    0x19e388bcc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 727
17  UIFoundation                    0x19e323fe0 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
18  UIKitCore                       0x19eaeaec0 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 131
19  UIFoundation                    0x19e388bcc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 727
20  UIFoundation                    0x19e388dec UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1271
21  UIFoundation                    0x19e323fe0 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
22  UIKitCore                       0x19eae5e90 -[NSCoder+ 7241360 (UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 491
23  UIKitCore                       0x19eae8a58 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1067
24  UIKitCore                       0x19efda9c4 -[UIStoryboard __reallyInstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 283
25  UIKitCore                       0x19efda85c -[UIStoryboard _instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 127
26  UIKitCore                       0x19ee6c390 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 183
27  UIKitCore                       0x19ee6c8fc -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 275
28  UIKitCore                       0x19ee6b068 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1003
29  UIKitCore                       0x19e5db03c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 151
30  UIKitCore                       0x19eaa6d68 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 111
31  UIKitCore                       0x19e5dbb70 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 211
32  UIKitCore                       0x19e5db59c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 295
33  UIKitCore                       0x19e5db98c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 755
34  UIKitCore                       0x19e5db214 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 339
35  UIKitCore                       0x19e5df930 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke_2 + 195
36  UIKitCore                       0x19e9c5604 +[BSAnimationSettings+ 6059524 (UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 855
37  UIKitCore                       0x19eac0a0c _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 259
38  UIKitCore                       0x19e5df66c __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 155
39  UIKitCore                       0x19eac08f4 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 107
40  UIKitCore                       0x19e5df4c4 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 391
41  UIKitCore                       0x19e445ba4 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 639
42  UIKitCore                       0x19e4446a4 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 255
43  UIKitCore                       0x19e4458d4 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 235
44  UIKitCore                       0x19ee693fc -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 551
45  UIKitCore                       0x19e9ebe08 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 375
46  FrontBoardServices              0x19ff86ffc -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 439
47  FrontBoardServices              0x19ffad5a0 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.168 + 115
48  FrontBoardServices              0x19ff91ebc -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 239
49  FrontBoardServices              0x19ffad234 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 343
50  libdispatch.dylib               0x19a9c433c _dispatch_client_callout + 19
51  libdispatch.dylib               0x19a9c70d4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 263
52  FrontBoardServices              0x19ffd36c4 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 47
53  FrontBoardServices              0x19ffd3370 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 431
54  FrontBoardServices              0x19ffd38dc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 31
55  CoreFoundation                  0x19ac9faf4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 27
56  CoreFoundation                  0x19ac9fa48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 83
57  CoreFoundation                  0x19ac9f198 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 195
58  CoreFoundation                  0x19ac99f38 __CFRunLoopRun + 795
59  CoreFoundation                  0x19ac998f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 479
60  GraphicsServices                0x1a50b0604 GSEventRunModal + 163
61  UIKitCore                       0x19ee6d358 UIApplicationMain + 1943
62  XxxxxxxxxxxX                    0x1042bfff4 main + 32756 (main.m:23)
63  libdyld.dylib                   0x19ab152dc start + 3


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ab0adf0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aa2a930 pthread_kill + 228
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019a9b8ba4 abort + 104
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019aaddf40 __cxxabiv1::__aligned_malloc_with_fallback+ 65344 (unsigned long) + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019aacf8c8 demangling_unexpected_handler+ 6344 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019aa38f0c _objc_terminate+ 24332 () + 132
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019aadd3cc std::__terminate(void (*)+ 62412 ()) + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019aadd358 std::terminate+ 62296 () + 44
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a9c4350 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a9c70d4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
10  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019ffd36c4 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
11  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019ffd3370 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 432
12  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019ffd38dc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019ac9faf4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019ac9fa48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 84
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019ac9f198 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 196
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019ac99f38 __CFRunLoopRun + 796
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019ac998f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
18  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a50b0604 GSEventRunModal + 164
19  UIKitCore                       0x000000019ee6d358 UIApplicationMain + 1944
20  XxxxxxxxxxxX                    0x00000001042bfff4 main + 32756 (main.m:23)
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019ab152dc start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aa319c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aa319c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aa319c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aa319c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019aae8784 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019aae7ba8 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019ac9f314 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019ac9a0a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1156
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019ac998f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
5   Foundation                      0x000000019afe2b18 -[NSRunLoop+ 31512 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
6   Foundation                      0x000000019afe29f0 -[NSRunLoop+ 31216 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000019ef13840 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 156
8   Foundation                      0x000000019b11cc10 __NSThread__start__ + 864
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aa298fc _pthread_start + 168
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aa319d4 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aa319c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000016bb45f30   x5: 0x000000016bb464e0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000700
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x97607b88fb8b2847  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x000000000000002e  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001dcaaa808  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x0000000104611960  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000104611960
   x24: 0x0000000000001e03  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x000000016bb46cb0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x00000001e5b54000   fp: 0x000000016bb46440   lr: 0x000000019aa2a930
    sp: 0x000000016bb46420   pc: 0x000000019ab0adf0 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the report it seems that one or more of your xib or storyboard files contain a UISearchDisplayController element. This element is not available anymore in the latest iOS versions. I would suggest removing all UISearchDisplayController instances from your project.

Comment: Thanks! I put this code together in 2011. There was a storyboard in the App in fact using a UISearchDisplayController. I removed it and it passed review. I is still puzzling that I could not reproduce the crash the reviewer was experiencing though.